# Reference a file in a different folder bash

Tags: bash

So my folder structure looks like this:

`User/name/test/files`

Each of those is a different folder. We are currently working in `test`, where we have the bash script, `testscript`. In the `files` folder, we have a text file, aptly named, `testfile`. `testfile.txt` contains a line of text.

`testscript` looks like this:

`#!/bin/bash
cat < User/name/test/files/testfile.txt`

This displays the file. But what if I wanted to distribute this on Git? It wouldn't run successfully on other computers.

I guess my question is, how can I tell a script what it's current directory is so I may access other files in deeper folders? Would it be a smarter idea to place the file in the folder with the test script?

Comment: You use a dot to denote the current directory. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: Possibly? So if I references testfile.txt like `./files/testfile.txt` that should work?

Comment: That worked. Why can't that be an easy find on Google?

Comment: "bash current directory" has me editing my $PATH values and such. Regardless, I appreciate the help. You answered the question.

Comment: @jagdpanzer Search for bash relative paths..

Comment: Technically, it's not just a bash /shell feature. CMD also uses that. It's somewhat a standard command line thing...  http://askubuntu.com/questions/25813/commandline-shortcut-for-current-directory-similar-to-for-home-directory

Comment: @jagdpanzer : Also, kindly SO thoroughly  before asking, if a similar question already exist, it saves  you time.

Comment: @sjsam Gotcha. Voted to close.